# c++ and xcode - calling objects function throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, xcode

This code works fine in VS2010 but now I am trying to port it to my mac with xcode 4.6 and it's giving me some bad access errors at run time. Basically I have a board class which contains a 2d array of tiles, when I create the board I can access the tiles functions but when I later run my draw function it gives me bad access. Here is a sample of my board class.

Board.h

```
#include "Tile.h"
class Board
{
private:
    //This is the GameBoard of a 2D array of Tiles
    Tile *** GameBoard;
    void CreateBoard(const int size);
void FillValues();
    ...
public:
Board(int size);
void DrawBoard();
    ...
}
```

Board.cpp

```
Board::Board(const int size)
{
won=false;
lost=false;
BoardSize =size;
GameBoard = new Tile**[size];
CreateBoard(size);
}

void Board::CreateBoard(const int size)
{
    ...
    FillValues()
}

void Board::FillValues()
{
    for(int x=1;x<BoardSize+1;x++)
    {
        for(int y =1;y<BoardSize+1;y++)
        {
            if (GameBoard[x][y]->Type()=="NumberTile")
            {
                                int neighbors = CountNeighbours(x,y);
                GameBoard[x][y]->SetValue(neighbors);
                                //This works
            }
        }
    }
}

void Board::DrawBoard()
{
for(int i=0;i<=BoardSize+1;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<=BoardSize+1;j++)
    {
        if (GameBoard[i][j]->Type() != "BorderTile") {
            GameBoard[i][j]->Draw();
            //This does not work, i get the error when it tries to use ->Type()
        }
    }
}
}

...
```

I call the functions like this

```
GI = new Board(SCREEN_SIZE);
GI->DrawBoard();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GameBoard = new Tile**[size];
```

This just creates an array of `Tile**`. You don't yet have any actual `Tile`s or even `Tile*`s and later, when you're trying to access elements of the array with `GameBoard[x][y]->`, you're hitting undefined behaviour.

As you have it, you would need to do this:

```
GameBoard = new Tile**[size];      // Allocate an array of Tile**
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  GameBoard[i] = new Tile*[size];  // Allocate an array of Tile*
  for (int j = 0; i < size; j++) {
     GameBoard[i][j] = new Tile(); // Allocate an array of Tile
  }
}
```

However, this is awful. It's three lots of dynamic allocation that you have to remember to tidy up at the end (and tidy up correctly).

A simpler approach would be to just have an 2D array of tiles:

```
Tile GameBoard[CONSTEXPR_SIZE][CONSTEXPR_SIZE];
```

Or better yet, use the `std::array` container:

```
std::array<std::array<Tile, CONSTEXPR_SIZE>, CONSTEXPR_SIZE> GameBoard;
```

Here, the size given has to be a constant expression. If you need it to be dynamically sized, use a `std::vector` instead.

---

In the comments below, you say the size of your array is actually `BoardSize+1`. Still, you are iterating over too many elements in both your outer and inner `for` loops:

```
for(int i=0;i<=BoardSize+1;i++)
```

This should be:

```
for(int i=0; i<BoardSize+1; i++)
```

---

Also in the comments below, you say that `Type` returns a `char*`. That means you can't do your string comparison like this:

```
GameBoard[i][j]->Type() != "BorderTile"
```

This simply performs pointer comparison, since the left operand is a `char*` and the right operand is convertible to `const char*`. It *doesn't* compare the strings themselves. Instead, you want:

```
GameBoard[i][j]->Type() != std::string("BorderTile")
```

This will force `std::string` comparison to be used.

Comment: Thanks, I am creating each tile as you show in your example, sorry for leaving that out in the createboard function. I do see the need for redesigning my program to use the std array instead. But my problem is my FillValues function loops through the gameboard fine, however when I try using DrawBoard() from outside the class and use the same ->Type() function on for example GameBoard[1][1] which I know I created in CreateBoard it wont work?

Comment: @UberBrainChild Also, what type does `Type` return?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I added a Tile of type border and I also add +1 to my size when creating the board so I am pretty sure I'm not out of scope. Type() returns a string representing the tile type

Comment: @UberBrainChild If you have `+1` then keep the `+1` but don't *also* use `<=`. You are going past the end of your array. Also, I asked specifically what type it returns. Is it a `const char*` or a `std::string`?

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe that solved it... haha Thanks! It was the +1 in the for loops causing the error. Type() returns char *

Comment: @UberBrainChild Well then you have another bug. See my second edit.

Comment: Thanks, I will fix that as well!

Comment: Would you be able to tell my why I shouldn't add numbers like that in my for loop?

Comment: @UberBrainChild You mean the `+1`? Actually, I recommended that you keep the `+1` and instead change the `<=` to a `<`. Using `<=` means you go one too far.